# What is the best way to simplify Objects in JavaScript (perferably using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, performance

I have an Object that looks like this:

```
var dataSource = [{
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 2),
    name: "a",
    l: 24.00,
    h: 25.00,
    o: 25.00,
    c: 24.875
}, {
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 2),
    name: "a",
    l: 23.625,
    h: 25.125,
    o: 24.00,
    c: 24.875
}, {
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 3),
    name: "a",
    l: 26.25,
    h: 28.25,
    o: 26.75,
    c: 27.00
}, {
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 4),
    name: "c",
    l: 26.50,
    h: 27.875,
    o: 26.875,
    c: 27.25
}, {
```

and so on...
I want to combine entries by their date, meaning if two datapoints have the same date and name, I want to add them together so the output would be:

```
var dataSource = [{
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 2),
    name: "a",
    l: 47.625,
    h: 50.125,
    o: 49.00,
    c: 49.75
}, {
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 3),
    name: "a",
    l: 26.25,
    h: 28.25,
    o: 26.75,
    c: 27.00
}, {
    date: new Date(1994, 2, 4),
    name: "c",
    l: 26.50,
    h: 27.875,
    o: 26.875,
    c: 27.25
}, {
```

Right now the best way I can think of doing this would be a for loop that runs until the size of the object doesnt change any more. Is there a better way of doing this, possibly a jquery function similar to grep that could do this?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with jQuery? jQuery is for DOM manipulation, not general js stuff.

Comment: @SuperStormer I don't think so, They have lots of methods such as Ajax which is just an xhr call, but less code to write.

Comment: This is more of lodash/underscore's domain, if any at all. Also, Zawinski's law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `reduce()` call grouping elements by a compound key made of the the date concatenated with the name (`o.date.valueOf() + o.name`), summing the relevant keys and then calling `Object.values()` on the result to return an array of the merged objects.

```js
const dataSource = [{ date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a", l: 24.00, h: 25.00, o: 25.00, c: 24.875 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a", l: 23.625, h: 25.125, o: 24.00, c: 24.875 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 3), name: "a", l: 26.25, h: 28.25, o: 26.75, c: 27.00 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 4), name: "c", l: 26.50, h: 27.875, o: 26.875, c: 27.25 }];

const
  sumKeys = (a, b) => ['l', 'h', 'o', 'c'].forEach(k => a[k] += b[k]),
  grouped = Object.values(
    dataSource.reduce((a, o) => {
      const entry = (a[o.date.valueOf() + o.name] ??= { name: o.name, date: o.date.valueOf(), l: 0, h: 0, o: 0, c: 0 });
      sumKeys(entry, o);
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or if you need to avoid [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) for [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment#browser_compatibility)...

```js
const dataSource = [{ date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a", l: 24.00, h: 25.00, o: 25.00, c: 24.875 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a", l: 23.625, h: 25.125, o: 24.00, c: 24.875 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 3), name: "a", l: 26.25, h: 28.25, o: 26.75, c: 27.00 }, { date: new Date(1994, 2, 4), name: "c", l: 26.50, h: 27.875, o: 26.875, c: 27.25 }];

const
  sumKeys = (a, b) => ['l', 'h', 'o', 'c'].forEach(k => a[k] += b[k]),
  grouped = Object.values(
    dataSource.reduce((a, o) => {
      const entry = (a[o.date.valueOf() + o.name] = a[o.date.valueOf() + o.name] || { name: o.name, date: o.date.valueOf(), l: 0, h: 0, o: 0, c: 0 });
      sumKeys(entry, o);
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const data = 
  [ { date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a"
    , l: 24.00, h: 25.00, o: 25.00, c: 24.875
    } 
  , { date: new Date(1994, 2, 2), name: "a"
    , l: 23.625, h: 25.125, o: 24.00, c: 24.875
    } 
  , { date: new Date(1994, 2, 3), name: "a"
    , l: 26.25, h: 28.25, o: 26.75, c: 27.00
    } 
  , { date: new Date(1994, 2, 4), name: "c"
    , l: 26.50, h: 27.875, o: 26.875, c: 27.25
    } 
  ] 
       
const Result = data.reduce((acc,c)=>
  {
  let same = acc.find(x=>x.date.getTime()===c.date.getTime()
                         && x.name===c.name)
  if(!same)
    acc.push({...c})
  else
    {
    same.l += c.l
    same.h += c.h
    same.o += c.o
    same.c += c.c  
    }
  return acc
  }, [])

console.log( Result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can track the date and name in a mapper first

```js
var dataSource = [{
  date: new Date(1994, 2, 2),
  name: "a",
  l: 24.00,
  h: 25.00,
  o: 25.00,
  c: 24.875
}, {
  date: new Date(1994, 2, 2),
  name: "a",
  l: 23.625,
  h: 25.125,
  o: 24.00,
  c: 24.875
}, {
  date: new Date(1994, 2, 3),
  name: "a",
  l: 26.25,
  h: 28.25,
  o: 26.75,
  c: 27.00
}, {
  date: new Date(1994, 2, 4),
  name: "c",
  l: 26.50,
  h: 27.875,
  o: 26.875,
  c: 27.25
}];

const mapper = dataSource.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.date] = acc[cur.date] || {};
  acc[cur.date][cur.name] = acc[cur.date][cur.name] || {};

  ["l", "h", "o", "c"].forEach(k => {
    acc[cur.date][cur.name][k] = (acc[cur.date][cur.name][k] || 0) + cur[k];
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = [];

Object.keys(mapper).forEach(d => {
  Object.keys(mapper[d]).forEach(name => {
    const item = mapper[d][name];
    result.push({
      date: d,
      name,
      l: item.l,
      h: item.h,
      o: item.o,
      c: item.c,
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer works, but the other answer is less code and faster, so I will use it instead

Answer (score 0):

```
  let arr = dataSource.reduce((cur, next) => {
    const flag = cur.some(ele => {
      return ele.date.valueOf() === next.date.valueOf() && ele.name === next.name
    })
    if(!flag) {
      cur.push(next)
    }
    return cur;
  }, [])
  console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This just skips over matches, it doesn't sum them.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.